# servo speed control

Tags: servo, speed

I use towerpro sg90 servo motor for arduino 
I want one move forward and backward 180 degrees
why does it move in one direction slower when the button is pressed

```
/*



*/

#include <VarSpeedServo.h> 

VarSpeedServo myservo;


const int servoPin = 6;
int SwitchPin = 7;
int switchstate = 0;
int lastswitchstate = 0;

void setup() { 
pinMode(SwitchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

myservo.attach(servoPin);  
myservo.write(0,180,true);
myservo.write(180,0,true);
} 

void loop() {

switchstate = digitalRead(SwitchPin);

if (switchstate != lastswitchstate) {
if (switchstate == LOW) {
myservo.write(0,180,true);
myservo.write(180,0,true);           

}
lastswitchstate = switchstate;


} 
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Cenk, you can format your code using the buttons on the editor. Also you may need to include more information such as what environment you're working in (I assume Arduino), what sort of servo and libraries you are using. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: you are not understanding the `myservo.write()` function .... look at the example code that is included with the library .... read the comments in the example code carefully

Comment: like I said before, look at the example code and read the comments in the code .... you are not using the myservo.write() function correctly

Answer (score 1):

> myservo.write(0,180,true);
>
> myservo.write(180,0,true);

The code is doing exactly what you told it do do (as always):

1. Move to position 0, using speed 180
2. Move to position 180, using speed 0 (probably the code uses a minimal speed here, as - IMHO - 0 would be a non-speed ...)

Comment: library code is defined as 0 full speed.
I say 180 degrees with full speed but it moves slower in one direction